# I want to get list of report and dashboards of account, contact, and opportunity object. is there any other way like soql to get that list?

Tags: salesforce, report, dashboard, soql

I want to get list of report and dashboards of account, contact, and opportunity object. is there any other way like soql to get that list? Tried soql like
Select Id,Dashboard.DeveloperName,Dashboard.Id,Dashboard.FolderName,Dashboard.title,CustomReportId from DashboardComponent where CustomReportId In (Select Id from Report where DeveloperName in ('ReportName_1','ReportName_2','ReportName_3'))
but did not get any result.